# simple MFC/C++ MIME Encoder?

Tags: c++, mfc, mime, encoder, decoder

I need a simple C++ compatible with MFC or ATL, MIME Encoder, I need it for sending MIME encoded text posts to a web server.

Where can I find a source code for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kdeforche/wt/blob/master/src/Wt/Mail/Message.C#L70

It's licensed under GPL, but you can buy a license if you want to redistribute closed source: http://www.emweb.be/